# High Service Broker queue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service-broker

My production database suffers from a large Service Broker message queue. It is around 2 million. I would like to decrease it as small as possible.

I have tried `dbcc dbreindex('sys.queue_messages_245995913')` from the DAC connection, based on the advice given by Remus Rusanu [here](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/09/dealing-with-large-queues/).

But when I look at the queue properties, the queue size remains the same.

Comment: Why do you think reindexing a system object under DAC would delete rows?

Comment: I apply the solution based on this link : http://rusanu.com/2010/03/09/dealing-with-large-queues/

Comment: Have the messages in the queue been processed?  Is retention turned on?

Comment: Did you verify that the other conditions Remus talks about are also present in your scenario? My guess is you're not operating at that scale, it's something far simpler, and your queue is actually full, not just full of unghosted rows.

Comment: This really sounds like it may be an issue with how the messages are being handled. Are you sure conversations are being closed?

Answer (score 1):

TRY `TOP 10000` INSTEAD of `1` to quickly read messages from Queue that will clean the queue faster

```
WAITFOR ( RECEIVE TOP ( 10000) 
                   CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), message_body))                  
                  FROM dbo.[EventNotificationQueue] 

> --into @message_body

                  ), TIMEOUT 1000
```